# Can't get Mac dictation custom commands to work

Tags: macos, speech-recognition, osx-yosemite, dictation

I use the Mac Yosemite built in dictation extensively, and I find it does a really good job of understanding my speech, at least when I'm speaking in complete sentences.

I also use the dictation commands that you find under accessibility in system preferences, Like scroll down and scroll up. (It even does a really good job of telling the difference between when I say "scroll down" as a command and when I say it as part of a sentence.)

BUT I can't for the life of me get any custom commands to work. For example, I have tried to bind "Close this" to cmd-w, and "tooth paste" to "success" (as an experiment).

**I can't get dictation to recognize these commands, ever.** I seem to be following the steps shown on every tutorial. It just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This is not a programming question, and therefore it is off-topic here. You may be able to get an answer at one of the other [se] sites such as [apple.se] or [su] instead. Information on this site's guidelines (like all [se] sites) can be found in the [help].

Comment: Thanks Ken, I see that you're right and I voted to close.

Comment: Asked in Ask Different: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192205/mac-dictation-custom-commands-not-working